# html form code for website not working

Tags: html, forms

Hi I am currently using the following code for my form under contacts, however it is not working. I am not sure why

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input type="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Budget Select</option>
            <option>$600 to $1200</option>
            <option>$1200 to $2200</option>
            <option>$2200 to $2400</option>
            <option>$2400 to $4000</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Event details or enquires"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <form method="post" action="mailto:hello@vintagebella.com.au">
            <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have two form starting tags, try to move the action to the top form tag.

Comment: `mailto:` doesn’t “work” in general ... it relies on the user having a mail client configured on the device in some way or other, and that will not always be the case. And if I were to visit your site from an internet cafe, a mail client there would probably not be configured to use _my_ email address. You should implement a proper contact form with a server-side mailer instead instead.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Try following code,

```html
<form method="post" action="mailto:hello@vintagebella.com.au">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><select class="form-control">
                    <option>Budget Select</option>
                    <option>$600 to $1200</option>
                    <option>$1200 to $2200</option>
                    <option>$2200 to $2400</option>
                    <option>$2400 to $4000</option></select> </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Event details or enquires"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
 
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Please share what you changed, simply posting new code won't help anyone figure out what the issue was nor how to solve it themselves.

Comment: Thank you this worked however, i was wondering is there a way for it to submit the actual form with the options instead of sending an email ? Thank you

Comment: U need to use backend code to submit the form & u will able to store the details in database as well.

Comment: Thanks Santhoshkumar, but i am clueless how to do that :(

Comment: Hi Santhoskumar, I tried a few times with the backend code but not really getting anywhere could you kindly provide me steps on how to do this ?

Comment: helo @MariaBianco, u want to store the data in database?

Comment: yes please Santhoshkumar, i am currently with godaddy heard i cant do php?

Comment: U can use php and mysql in godaddy, just configure.

Comment: Thank you so i have created the php file now my code reads as follows: <form action="enquiries.php" method="post"> but does that mean I will still need to create a table form within the phpmyAdmin? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hv corrected the code. Try below code.

```
 <form method="post" action="mailto:hello@vintagebella.com.au" >
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <input type="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><select class="form-control">
                <option>Budget Select</option>
                <option>$600 to $1200</option>
                <option>$1200 to $2200</option>
                <option>$2200 to $2400</option>
                <option>$2400 to $4000</option></select> </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Event details or enquires"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">

                <input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 
                </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: Hi Imran Thank you so much for fixing the code, this works and opens to send an email however doesnt include the budget select options. is there any way for it to hit submit with the inputted info on the form?

Answer (score 0):

Use one form instead of two. And add Second form's functionlity into first one